# Problems with wrapfigure, numbers appear in front of photo

Tags: wrapfigure

I'm new to Latex but trying to put in a photo in a CV, using wrapfigure.
The intention is to fit it on the same line as some text, which works fine as long as the `{l}{0.3\textwidth}` is included.

The problem is that the text "l 0.3" then appear in front of the photo. Any idea how to hide this?

```
\newlength{\spacebox}
\settowidth{\spacebox}{8888888888}  
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}       

\newcommand{\MyName}[1]{ % Name
        \Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} \hfill #1
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\textwidth}
    \vspace*{-5em}
        \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{photo}
\end{wrapfigure}

\MyName{Name}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)Please extend your code fragment to be a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allws others to reproduce the output you get. Do you get any error messages? If so, which?

Comment: Did you include \usepackage{wrapfig}?  Do you get an error message about environment wrapfigure being undefined?